# How do you get Hadoop commands to work when you get the error "Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME"?

Tags: suse, hadoop

I had a Hadoop version 1.x installed on Linux SUSE 12.3.  I moved the directory somewhere else to back it up.  I tried to install Hadoop 3.0.  I expect Hadoop commands to work based on what I did.  I used open source Hadoop 3.0 files.  Hadoop commands do not work (with or without sudo).

I have set $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME to be both of these values but the problem kept happening:

```
$HADOOP_PREFIX

/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn
```

Neither worked.  Whenever I run a Hadoop command I get an error.  If I run this command:

```
sudo /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/hadoop version
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME

How do I get Hadoop commands to work?

Comment: kindly provide me with the output of `protoc --version`

Comment: Here is the output: `If 'protoc' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:   cnf protoc`  The only file with the name "protoc" was a directory named "protoc" in a hadoop-maven-plugins directory.